# How to understand OR operator in a PHP statement

Tags: php, expression

I have a below PHP statement:

```
   if( 
        (bool)is_check1($a) || 
        (bool)is_check2($a) || 
        (bool)is_check3($a)
    ){
        callFunctionA();
    }
```

I have debugged and got a news thing so strange that, even if `is_check1` returns `TRUE`, PHP still invoke the functions: `is_check2`, and `is_check3`.

In my mind, I always think that, if `is_check1` function returns TRUE, `PHP` SHOULD not invoke others.

But when I check it again, for example:

```
   if( 
        TRUE ||
        (bool)is_check2($a) || 
        (bool)is_check3($a)
    ){
        callFunctionA();
    }
```

The result is: `is_check2` and `is_check3` function do not invoke.

Please give me your advice to optimize in this case or am I missing something?

Comment: Which value is returned by `is_check1($a)` ?

Comment: This would not be possible. Something else is going on. Can you post a working example on e.g. ideone.com?

Comment: I can't reproduce: http://codepad.viper-7.com/IHeHvp

Comment: There is no point in those `(bool)` casts. They shouldn't break it but are unecessary, since in that situation the return values would be evaluated as booleans anyway.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: http://codepad.org/DhHOEfFG

Comment: Now, I got this problem. This point is my function returns incorrectly. Thanks so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attempting to reproduce with the following code:

```
function a() { echo 'a'; return true; }
function b() { echo 'b'; return true; }
function c() { echo 'c'; return true; }

if (a() || b() || c()) echo 'valid!';
if (true || b() || c()) echo 'valid!';
if ((bool)a() || (bool)b() || (bool)c()) echo 'valid!';
```

Prints: `avalid!valid!avalid!`

That means the problem is probably the return values of your functions.

Comment: +1: [Beat me to it](http://codepad.org/E3O0qNxu)

Comment: I think the result SHOULD be:  `avalid!valid!avalid!`